# How to get the coordinates of the markers after a drag in vue2-google-map

Tags: vue.js

Good day, I want to get the new coordinates of my marker after I dragged them somewhere.

I tried the solutions of similar questions of my problem but it still doesn't work.

here's my code:

```
<GmapMarker
    v-for="(pin, index) in filterBeepStopsList"
    :key="index"
    :position="pin.location"
    :clickable="true"
    :draggable="true"
    @dragend="updateMarker(index,$event.latLng)"
    :icon="beepStopMarkerOption"
/>
```

methods

```
updateMarker(index,location){
    this.beepStops[index] = {
        location:{
            lat: location.lat(),
            lng: location.lng()
        }
    }
    this.henlo = location.lat()
},
```

I tried putting the .lat() value inside the `henlo` data but it is still empty. How do I solve this?

**Edit**: Or like the events doesn't even work at all. tried the @click one to center it on my screen, it doesn't  do its job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vue2-google-map change `@dragend` to `@drag`